# NDK r7c compiling issue

Tags: android, android-ndk

I just want to know does anyone having issue with NDK r7c on Windows 7 and Cygwin.
I am getting this message:
"/usr/bin/mount.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot 
open shared object file: No such file or directory" 
On version r7 and r7b, my codes compile just fine.

Thanks in advance for any tips on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that it's related, but it could possibly be: I just posted a question very similar to yours.

The general answer is that the path to cygwin1.dll file needs to be in your PATH somewhere  -  that's the easiest solution in most cases. This didn't solve the problem for me, however - my problem is still outstanding.

Take a look at the dialogue surrounding my question and see if there are any solutions for you.

[Here's the question I asked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092730/launching-cygwin-built-executable-from-java-on-windows-7-fails-with-error-while)

Regards,
R