# Launching CYGWIN-built executable from Java on Windows 7 fails with "error while loading shared libraries: ?: No such file or directory"

Tags: java, c, windows, cygwin, shared-libraries

The code in question has worked in more or less the exact same configuration on earlier releases of Windows, however, it is not known to have run on Windows 7 YET! That's what I need to solve now.

Briefly, some C code performs some configuration and security checks before launching a java program, passing some data that would be neigh-into-impossible to do easily in Java. The Java in turn, at the appropriate time launches the same C code which then itself launches a different Java program. The second program launch needs to be completely independent, (think nohup) hence the second launch.

What's happening now is that the C program launches the Java program in the ordinary way, but when the Java tries to launch the C program, it errors out like this:

> /cygdrive/c/opt/ST/v3.3/bin/ST.exe: error while loading shared
>   libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

Because Windows has been such a bear over the years, the C code is written in the posix environment of Cygwin, but all it really does is ordinary C types of things (nothing about it is unique to Cygwin and, indeed, in the past it has been built with Microsoft's development tools, but that environ is not available at present). The Cygwin environ adds a lot of other great benefits, like command-line management of services (cygrunsrv) and a full-on 'nix-like environment (bash, etc). In fact, because Windows has changed how one launches a program from Java so many times, Cygwin helps standardize the Java launch code. Here's an excerpt:

```
  if (ClientOS.indexOf("Windows") != -1)
  {
     if (ClientOS.equals("Windows 95"))
     {
        cmd = "command.com /C ";
     } else if (ClientOS.equals("Windows 98"))
     {
        cmd = "command.com /C ";
        //cmd = "cmd.exe /C ";
     } else if (ClientOS.equals("Windows NT"))
     {
        cmd = "cmd.exe /C ";
     } else if (ClientOS.equals("Windows 2000"))
     {
        cmd = "cmd.exe /C ";
     } else if (ClientOS.equals("Windows XP"))
     {
        cmd = "cmd.exe /C ";
     } else {
        cmd = "cmd.exe /C ";
     }
     if (cygwin)
     {
        cmd += Shell+" '"+Command+"'";
     } else {
        cmd += Command;
     }
  } else {
     cmd = Command;
  }
```

(Yes, the if structure could be better optimized.)

In this case, "Shell" equals:

```
Shell=C:/cygwin/bin/bash -c
```

And, there's a test program to ensure the above and supporting code works OK - it runs a bit of shell program and ensures it got back what it thought it should. It says:

> Checking the ability to run a program using a shell...
>          Yes, shell programs work fine.

The final contents of cmd look something like this:

> cmd.exe /C C:/cygwin/bin/bash -c '/cygdrive/c/opt/ST/v3.3/bin/ST.exe'

**WHAT I SUSPECT:**

I suspect what's going on is that the Cygwin1.DLL file isn't being found properly. It lives in C:/cygwin/bin/cygwin1.dll

**NOTE THAT** both the system-level PATH and the Cygwin PATH include the path to the cygwin .dll files. Moving a copy of cygwin1.dll to the bin directory where the target executable lives didn't work either.

Would LD_LIBRARY_PATH lend any help here? If so, any idea how it is to be set?

Other ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak Are you being sarcastic? The same set of code needs to "run everywhere" - and, with this exception - and not yet Android phones - it does. It's presently on Solaris, BSD, OSX, and it works OK pretty much everywhere it has been tried on....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
C:/cygwin/bin/bash -c '/cygdrive/c/opt/ST/v3.3/bin/ST.exe'
```

This won't work because your working directory is where you reside when you executed this command. You will have to copy the cygwin dependent dlls to the directory you execute this from. Othwerwise, you will have to place the cygwin bin directory in your system PATH variable, not sure you want to do that, can cause dll hell.

Also, if you're using anything in your profile, you need to add --login parameter to bash:

```
bash --login -c
```

Also, print the final command out at the end, before you spawn the process:

```
printf('%s\n',cmd)
```

Just to be sure it's exactly what you want.

You may also run the program with strace, if you're unsure about the dlls being referenced.

Comment: C:/cygwin/bin/bash -c 'PATH=/bin:$PATH ; /cygdrive/c/opt/ST/v3.3/bin/ST.exe'

Comment: Err? Is this an updated command? Are you asking a question here?

Comment: @JasonHuntley Do you mean to say the cygwin1.dll needs to exist in the same directory as the image I'm calling? Surely you don't mean the _default_working_directory_ has to be set where the cygwin1.dll resides?!

Comment: @Joshua Tried that; didn't work. Too bad - it would have been an easy and elegant solution! BTW, I took you to mean that because /bin is the location of cygwin1.dll, that should do it...

Comment: @JasonHuntley I tried putting the cygwin dll into the same directory as the image I'm trying to launch, but that didn't work.

Comment: @JasonHUntley Re: your edit additions: Using _nothing_ from any user profile; The actual command is above, minus the many arguments to the command, AND minus the "cmd.exe /C" that can be seen in the code (added to the question above for clarity). Still not working. ANY version of trying this from the command line always works, so clearly Java is omitting some elements from the environment, even the things I intentionally tell Java about, apparently!

Comment: Richard, do you have a log, stacktrace, or the error message? Is it possible the missing dll is in relation to bash and not your process?

Comment: @JasonHuntley No, there's no other output. It's not getting to my program... I suppose I could try launching some completely unrelated, Windows-Only program, but I'm not sure that helps me solve the problem.

Comment: @RichardT, I would devise a way to print out more debug details. Log to a file via log4j or similar. Add a try/catch block in java, catch the exception and print it out to the log file. You could also try adding your command to a bash script and call your command in the cmd.sh. Then you could echo out path variables and env settings to file to check your shell environment.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways.

cygwin1.dll needs to be in %WINDIR%\system32 or equivalent.

or

you modify the PATH variable to add the path to cygwin1.dll in the caller's environment.

or

you call a .bat file that sets the environment before you call the cygwin built exe.

or

you build a standalone version of the .exe (i.e. no cygwin dependency).

Comment: Yes, I seem to recall solutions like this from the past. However, I tried... Choice 1 above: didn't work. Choice 2 was already implemented before I posted my question. Choice 3 - I'm no expert at bat files, but that's in effect what happens above; what's your suggestion for how to "set the environment"? And your last one isn't practical at the moment - and would like to avoid it since there must be a solution that avoids that step!

Comment: OK, but now I've tried almost all of this: moving the cygwin1.dll didn't work, modifying PATH didn't work, calling a .bat file didn't work, and the last one, I didn't try because it would have added significantly to my burdens... And, I found a solution (will provided it in a minute)... Thank you for the ideas, though.

Comment: make sure you get the right environment, call your batch file with cmd.exe /c \path\batchfile.bat

Comment: and in your batch file, you can launch your script or exe under bash like \cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -i /home/your_home_dir/script_name

Comment: also look at \cygwin\cygwin.bat then you can see how it is started

Comment: @RichardT What was the solution in the end?